# Android: Is there a way to make facebook.dialog less ugly? - Screenshot attached

Tags: android, facebook

I'm very close to having what I need for my facebook dialog, the post is working successfully, which has taken me a fair amount of time as i've struggled with the facebook sdk.

When I open the dialog to post a message to the feed ( or when I call authorise in a dialog ), it shows as shown here:
http://minus.com/mg6utFaHf

I'm looking for something more like this:
[image]

Any ideas why mind is showing so... ugly?
It's very square, in a webview, with the X in the top left.

Thanks, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The new Facebook SDK should allow you to use the built in Facebook app to do such things via intent.
In alternative you could use the Intent ACTION_SEND to achieve what you want.

Comment: I believe this will open up a share dialog window offering the user options such as email etc. This isn't really what I'm looking for. I am currently using the facebook SDK. If I use Action_Send, I would surely also be assuming the user has the facebook app installed?

Answer (score 0):

The new SDK of theirs implements a way of authorizing called Single Sign-On which searches the device for the presence of the Facebook app and sends an Intent to that app which will authorize for you. If the Facebook app is not found then it will fall back to the dialog method.

You'll still be stuck with square iOS-y like design for in app sharing, invite friends, etc. The only way I can think of getting around this is to use FQL but how to do that is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks, seems really odd, as the facebook app is installed on the device the screenshot came from. When it authorizes it does go to a new activity and then back ( which I assume is the facebook app ), but then it shows the dialog as above. The line i'm using to show the dialog is this: facebook.dialog(SlotMachineActivity.this, "feed", params,new SampleDialogListener());

I'm not sure why this wouldn't use the facebook app, or why it has to have such square edges

Comment: Could be the FB app is an old version but because the dialogs are essentially webviews they can update the website displayed in the dialog webview without having to update the app

Answer (score 0):

http://minus.com/mg6utFaHf is just the standard facebook Feed dialog ... see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ ... just change www. to m. as for example `https://m.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=123050457758183&link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&name=Facebook%20Dialogs&caption=Reference%20Documentation&description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response`

Said that if you want it different you have to implement UI and post data by your own by Graph api